# Scale Connected UV Faces on Individual Origins

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have a UV unwrapped mesh with multiple UV faces. They are all part of the same UV island. I want to scale all of them down on their individual origins, so each UV face will shrink, but remain in the same location.

Right now, the only way I can do this is by disabling sticky selection mode and scaling down individual faces one at a time. This is incredibly tedious and I wish to automate it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can set the pivot point to individual origins, but you need to separate the faces for them to scale individually.

Comment: How would I separate the faces without having to re unwrap the mesh?

Comment: The slow way is select a uv face and Alt-V - the quick way is to pin the verts and then add a seam to all edges and unwrap. Pinning the verts will keep them in place.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out a way to do this that works in my case:

Assuming the connectivity of your UV map topology is similar to your object:

1. On the object side: Select your target object faces as usual.
2. (UV unwrap if you haven't already done it)
3. On the object side: Select -> Checker Deselect
4. On the UV side: Select all, set individual origins, scale. As long as none of the visible vertices are touching, each face will scale along its own origin.

Answer (score 2):

This problem bugged me so hard I decided just to waste 2 days by learning some basic phython and writing an addon against it. So if anyone wants it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YP21H_8iTyqBn2IRfoPyx5klZ4QIVY9t/view?usp=sharing) you can find it. With the addon you can scale the UVs of the associated selected faces in the 3d View by a self determinated factor.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do it in the UI, so I wrote a script. 
This is what I came up with:

```py
import bpy
import mathutils
import bmesh

# Get the selected object and its mesh
obj = bpy.context.object
mesh = obj.data

# Create a bmesh from the mesh
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

# Get the active UV layer
uv_lay = bm.loops.layers.uv[0]

# Scale factor for the UVs
x = 0.9

# Iterate over the selected faces and their loops
for face in bm.faces:
    if face.select:
        # Calculate the UV face center
        loop_sum = mathutils.Vector((0, 0, 0))
        loop_count = len(face.loops)
        for loop in face.loops:
            uv = loop[uv_lay].uv
            loop_sum.xy += uv
        center = loop_sum / loop_count
        for loop in face.loops:
            # Move the UV coordinates to the middle
            loop[uv_lay].uv -= center.xy
            # Scale the UV coordinates by x
            loop[uv_lay].uv *= x
            # Move the UV coordinates back to where they were
            loop[uv_lay].uv += center.xy

# Update the mesh with the changes
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
bm.free()
```